# JGit, remove tags no longer in remote

Tags: jgit

This is a question specific to the JGit api.
I would like to replicate in JGit the same behavior of the following Git command:
`git fetch --prune --prune-tags`, which basically removes, from the local repository, the tags which are no longer existing in remote.
I cant see this option in the [API](https://archive.eclipse.org/jgit/site/4.7.0.201704051617-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/api/FetchCommand.html)

Comment: Did you try to set `removeDeletedRefs` to `true`, IIRC, this setting removes all stale refs.